Google OAuth granular Consent with google fit api
We are using googlefit and logging in with oauth
The content displayed on the oAuth consent screen states that your name, email address, language preferences, and profile photo are provided.
I looked at the link below, and found that it says the following:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/granular-permissions
For applications that request only Sign-In scopes (email, profile, and openid), these scopes are combined into one consent. Users either approve or deny the entire request. In the other words, if applications only request Sign-In scopes (one, two, or all three), the granular permission consent screen is not applicable.
It seems that the information requested by our app falls within the scope of login and is not segmented. Does googlefit fall into the segmentation scope?
If you say you have to do it, how should you do it on Android?
I looked through the documentation but couldn't find how to do it on Android. If there is a guide document, please let me know

I am assuming you are referring to this https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization. In this case, the granular permissions changes apply as google fit scope is not part of the SignIn scopes.
The How to handle granular permissions documentation outlines the concept and best practice on how to handle, test, and verify granular permissions. The code sample is just an example, by no mean it covers all SDKs and platforms.
However, the best practice still applies for any platforms and SDKs. Consult the SDK you use on how to apply the best practice.
